# Unable to debug in XCode 7 beta 2

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, ios9

I am trying to debug my code with XCode 7 beta 2. I can't see values of my variables and when i try to print a variable (p ) i receive the following error:

```
error: Error in auto-import:
failed to get module '<my_app_name>' from AST context
```

I could not find a way to fix it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, this issue was resolved by a clean build ⌥⇧⌘K